# XSLT: in text element, how to replace line break (<br/>) with blank space?

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

NOTE:  I am using `xsltproc` on OS X Yosemite.

The source content for an XSLT transformation is HTML.  Some
text nodes contain line breaks (<br/>).  In the transformed
content (an XML file), I wish to convert the line breaks to spaces.

For example, I have:

```
<div class="location">London<br />Hyde Park<br /></div>
```

I want to transform this element like so:

```
<xsl:element name="location">
  <xsl:variable name="location" select="div[@class='location']"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$location"/>
</xsl:element>
```

What happens is the <br /> are simply removed the output:

```
<location>LondonHyde Park</location>
```

I do have other templates that are involved:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|script"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

What XSLT operations are required to transform the <br />'s here
to a single space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:value-of` and add a template to handle `<br/>`.

You would also need to modify `<xsl:template match="node()|script"/>` because `node()` also selects text nodes. You can replace `node()` with `processing-instruction()|comment()` if you need to, but they would not be output by default anyway.

Here's a working example:

**Input**

```
<div class="location">London<br />Hyde Park<br /></div>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="script"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='location']">
        <location><xsl:apply-templates/></location>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<location>London Hyde Park </location>
```

If you don't want the trailing space, you could either...

- put the `xsl:apply-templates` in a variable (`$var`) and use `normalize-space()` in an `xsl:value-of`. Like: `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($var)"/>`
- update the match for the `br` element. Like: `br[not(position()=last())]`